# Working with duplicate file names between two directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have just started today with my first script writing and I have a question.

In `C:\dlls` I have about 30 `.dll` files.

In `C:\upgrade` I have all the `.dll` files I need to upgrade.

My question is is it possible to write a batch script with the following logic:

Check directory `C:\upgrade` for all existing `.dll` files. If they exist, get their file names, then append `_` to any existing matching named `.dll` in `C:\dlls` before copying it to `C:\dlls`.

Currently I have developed some logic but with this I need to check for each `.dll`:

```
cd ..\Dlls

if exist ..\upgrade\icudt54.dll (
    if exist icudt54_.dll (
        del icudt54_.dll
    )
    ren icudt54.dll icudt54_.dll
    move ..\upgrade\icudt54.dll .
        set \A n=n%+1
    echo icudt54.dll upgraded.
) else (
echo File icudt54.dll does not exist in UPGRADE FOLDER!
)
```

Comment: You are doing great for your first batch script. What will help you is the `FOR` statement. Use `FOR /?` to read the details. Change `set \A` to `set /A`.

Comment: In fact you should change `set \A n=n%+1` to `Set/A n+=1`.

Comment: @Compo Just asking: Is `set/a ....` more recommended than `set /a`? Because I found you often do so in your scripts.

Comment: I like to be different! I wouldn't recommend it as a best practice because it doesn't work with every command, some of them need the separating space. In the case of `Set`, `Set/A` and `Set/P` I see them as three completely different commands as opposed to one with different switches, so for that reason I like to merge the switch with the command. _It also saves that all important byte!_